# IDbCommandTreeInterceptor for exact DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` for handling soft delete functionality, and I have facet situation when I have to read all entities deleted and not. For that I want to have separated "readonly" `DbContext` and want my interceptor do not handle queries from that `DbContext`. Is there any possibility to add interceptor for exact dbContext or handle it from interceptor some how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your special context is of type `DontInterceptContext` you may use the interceptionContext, like this :

```
public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
{
    ...

    if (interceptionContext.DbContexts.OfType<DontInterceptContext>().Any())
            return;
```

Checking the value of a property in the `Any()` is also an option